Adding SMA connector to a 433 MHz remote
I need to open a gate from 100 meters distance. This gate uses a 433 MHz rolling code remote.
The only option I see, is to connect an active amplifier to the remote using a SMA connector. Those devices can be easily found online.
Can someone help me identify the antenna and the ground on the PCB of this specific remote, so that I can solder a SMA connector?

EDIT: Proposed approach: scratch the PCB mask and solder antenna to the red highlighted part and GND to the blue highlighted part.


"MHz", not "mhz"! Capitals matter!

On the back of the PCB there are only the buttons

@user1850479 What is on the back? The antenna is perfectly visible in the picture. Also amplifying the ISM band transmission can block a lot of other important traffic so it is likely illegal wherever you live.

The gate is in the middle of nowhere, the nearest neighbour is c. 4km as the crow flies. What do you think of the approach I added in the question?

@user3161330 It does not matter where the gate is. In most jurisdictions, posession, manufacture and use of an illegal transmitter is still illegal, so you can get in trouble. Even if it is not your intention, it still allows accidentally blocking the car door remotes and everything else using the 433 MHz ISM band within 100m radius of the transmitter. Rather than try to modify the 433 MHz transmitter, a better way would be to open the gate with e.g. a standard phone call, SMS, or with an app sending a command via the Internets or just a web page. Much easier that trying to hack the RF remote.

You could investigate what will happen if you would just connect a better passive antenna. These kind of PCB antennas are often so-so.

I believe the antenna is the rounded "M" shaped trace along the upper edge of the PCB. At it's right end is the feedpoint with an SMT part (probably a capacitor) connecting it to the rest of the circuit.
As others have pointed out, it is illegal to add an amplifier to this 433 MHz transmitter. Since the transmission is short in duration and you are in a rural area, it's unlikely anyone will be affected and raise a complaint. But I would like to suggest a legal alternative. Instead of modifying the transmitter, add a directional antenna to the gate receiver, pointed toward the location from which you intend to operate the gate. Yagi antennas are readily available for this band. Even a TV antenna should work. Cheap, legal, and worth a try.

Also, doubling the height of either antenna gives another 6dB, so put the gate antenna as high as possible, and hold the tx remote above your head instead of waist height.
